# Confused myself with a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Before you look at the code know that this will not become live so there will be no need to protect against `mysql` injection or use PDO or mysqli

Hi I'm really confused about how I'm supposed to get this section of my site to work this is the simple version of my problem. To start off with I have a form that a user will enter the details of a video then they can also upload the video, when they click the send button all of the details will be posted to a second page, at the moment it just echos the selected details that was from the form.

this is the SQL query that I want the value to be inserted into using the variables this is currently working.

```
INSERT INTO careersintheclassroom.media 
(media_id
,subject_id
,section_id
,principle_id
,jobrole_id
,career_id
,title
,blurb
,verified
) VALUES 
(NULL
,'$Subject'
,'$Section'
,'$Principle'
,'$Job'
,'$Career'
,'$Title'
,'$Blurb'
, 0);
```

This is the page that the details are posted to.

```
<html>
<head>
<!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=/classroom/contributors.php">-->
</head>
</html> 

<?php

// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = 'Downloads./';//
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

$Title = $_POST['Title'];
$Blurb = $_POST['Blurb'];
$Subject = $_POST['cat'];
$Section = $_POST['typ'];
$Principle = $_POST['princ'];
$Verify = $_POST['verification'];
$Career = $_POST['career'];
$Job = $_POST['Job'];
echo "<br />";
echo "<pre>";

echo " <b>Your media has been uploaded</b><br /><br /> ";
echo "Title : ";        echo $Title;
echo "<br/>";
echo "Blurb : ";        echo $Blurb;
echo"<br />";
echo "catergory : ";    echo $Subject;
echo"<br />";
echo "section : ";      echo $Section;
echo"<br />";
echo"principle : ";     echo $Principle;
echo"<br />";
echo "job : ";          echo $Job;
echo"<br />";
echo "Career : ";       echo $Career;
echo "<br />";
echo "Verify : ";       echo $Verify;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />"; 

echo"INSERT INTO `careersintheclassroom`.`media` (`media_id`, `subject_id`, `section_id`, `principle_id`, `jobrole_id`, `career_id`, `title`, `blurb`, `verified`) 
VALUES (NULL, '".$Subject."', '".$Section."', '".$Principle."', '".$Job."', '".$Career."', '".$Title."', '".$Blurb."', '0');";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n"; 

    echo "This is where I need to reference the function that runs the sql `INSERT`";

    }
 else 
{
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

my problem is i need to run the sql query on another page and then reference it to run from where i have stated and every time i try i get this echoed to my screen:

```
INSERT INTO `careersintheclassroom`.`media` (`media_id`, `subject_id`, `section_id`, `principle_id`, `jobrole_id`, `career_id`, `title`, `blurb`, `verified`) 
VALUES (NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0');
```

which I know means it cannot find the `$_POST` values because they are not within this page but everytime I put the `$_POST` on there then it makes the page break as in white screen nothing is displayed not even errors

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This is whre firebug (or equivalent) comes into its own. I use Firefox, which now seems to include a debugger as standard.

Comment: Use PDO anyways, in the worst case you'll end up learning something useful and up to date.

Comment: have you enabled `error_reporting`

Comment: error_reporting is enabled and I am also Learning PDO at the moment but this project was start with MySql and because of how many pages of code there is it would delay the projects completion date to redo do all of it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@$_POST will hide warnings

Or you could make sure the form has been posted before using them.

```
if( count($_POST) )
{
     // do something
}
```

$_GET will get them from the querystring rather than post or $_REQUEST will contain both $_GET and $_POST.

Comment: have you enabled error_reporting - anurupr - (from original comments) This will make your life easier =).

Comment: The form does post the values over to the first screen because I echo these to the page it is the second page that i am having trouble with i dont know how to post them over again.

Comment: You will have to put then into hidden/text inputs on the second page <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['var'] ?>" /> then post the form to the third page. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: You could also save them into the $_SESSION or $_COOKIE array if you want to keep track of them =)

Comment: that makes perfect sence and it has worked thank you i know its not the most elegant but it works exactly how i needed it to thank you if you put that as a answer ill accept cause that works